# What do Chinese write on a condolence card?

Tags: translation, meaning, culture

I was wondering what Chinese people would write when they write a condolence card. Is it just a translation from the English or are there specific sentences?

Comment: google   吊唁卡 one result  https://zh.wikihow.com/%E5%86%99%E5%90%8A%E5%94%81%E5%8D%A1 also see http://www.tthy.com/news/gd_bzwh4.asp

Comment: cf.e.g. http://qa.chineseembassy.org/chn/dtxw/t457297.htm
 中国驻卡塔尔大使馆举行全国哀悼日悼念活动, note 横幅标语：沉痛哀悼四川地震遇难同胞

Answer (score 2):

The link user6065 gave is somewhat misleading. Chinese do not have the tradition of writing a condolence CARD. The wiki how page provided seems to be a machine translation of the English wiki how. So it doesn't mean anything if you want to write its counterpart in Chinese. The second link is about 唁电/唁函, which is a very formal letter or message you write personally after someone's death, to express condolence to the family and friends of the dead. It's not very similar to a condolence card in English context. Only if having very important relationship with the dead, and not able to mourn for the dead in person, can you write a 唁电/唁函. It's weird to write one for the death of a pet, or your neighbor you don't know much about.

To write a well-composed 唁电/唁函, one needs to 遣詞雅正 用語沉肅 不枝詞蔓語 賣弄文采 亦不因陋就簡 有失鄭重.

Knowing all these above, let's talk about how to write a 唁电/唁函.

**Start with addressing the person or collective you write to:**

-No other words needed.

敬爱的陈旭师母：（incorrect）

陈旭师母：（correct）

**Main body**

-Main body comprises 4 parts:

-Express your deep sorrow at the news

-Exalt the dead for his good qualities and good deeds, from your memories.

-Express gratitude, for how the dead helped you during lifetime. And you will always remember the dead and his spirit.

-Comfort the family/friends, encourage them.

**Appropriate closing**

-There are many standard opts for this part.

**Your signature, time and date**

Answer (score 1):

Toosky Hierot wrote:

> *Chinese do not have the tradition of writing a condolence CARD*

Yes, I agree,  we do condolence mostly orally.

'condolence card'(慰問卡) is mostly accompany with delivered well-wishing gift like flower or fruit basket to family member of a deceased, or to sick or injured person. We do not need to send condolence card to someone who was dumped by his girlfriend or someone just failed a midterm exam

Here is what I would write in a condolence card:

> A friend's mother whom I had never seen died:

致 (your friend's name):

請節哀 (please not to wallowing in sadness too much)

~ (your name) 啓

> A friend just broken his leg in a car accident:

致 (your friend's name):

願你早日康復 (wish you recover soon)

~ (your name) 啓

*As for the formal newspaper post/ letter of condolence (唁电/唁函)  to the family members of a deceased, who had an important relationship with you, it is another matter. You should write a personal letter like you would to a dear friend*

Answer (score 1):

Actually Chinese people don't use condolence card, we use [挽联](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8C%BD%E8%81%94/10979605?fr=aladdin)

驾鹤西游 a euphemistic way to say someone passes by.

[image]
[image]